# Add padding to display: table-header-group

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin, padding

What I want to create is a responsive "table". So if if its on a browser it should be as follows:

Picture Name

Name Picture

Picture Name

However, when you view it on a phone screen (or other small screen), it needs to be like this:

Picture
Name
Picture
Name
etc.

That's why I used the `display:table-footer-group;` (or `table-header-group`) to switch the order of the columns. This works perfectly, so that is fine. However, all the padding then disappears and I have no idea how to read it. I found on the internet that `<thead>`s don't have padding, but how else can I add padding now? Because if you run the following snippet, the picture is too close to the text.

```css
.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.left2 {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.right {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.right2 {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.row {
  display: table;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img.team {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#box {
  border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
}

.centerjustify {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  img.team {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .left {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  .left2 {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
  .right2 {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  .right {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="centerjustify">
    <h2>Team Members</h2><br>
    <div id="box">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column left">
          <img class="team"
            src="https://www.birchgrovedental.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/empty-person.jpg">

        </div>
        <div class="column right">
          <h3>test</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
            ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
            dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
            ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
            quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
            arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
            Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
            Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend
            tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac,
            enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
            Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean
            imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper
            ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="column left2">
          <h3 style="text-align: right;">test</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
            ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
            dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
            ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
            quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
            arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
            Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
            Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend
            tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac,
            enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
            Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean
            imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper
            ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column right2">
          <img class="team"
            src="https://www.birchgrovedental.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/empty-person.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having a look. A small comment; you missed a `.` in your css for `.row`. You should update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have to use display:table, for row. It's quite easy to change the order of div's if you use flex. Also heaps better in making things responsive.[Please have a look at the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/havfed07/1/)

```
<div class="centerjustify">
        <h2>Team Members</h2><br>
        <div id="box">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column left">
                    <img class="team" src="https://www.birchgrovedental.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/empty-person.jpg">

                </div>
                <div class="column right">
                    <h3>test</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                        eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
                        Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row row--2">
                <div class="column left">
                    <h3 style="text-align: right;">test</h3>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                        eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
                        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
                        Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column right">
                    <img class="team" src="https://www.birchgrovedental.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/empty-person.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*,
     ::after,
     ::before {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

```
.centerjustify {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 15px;
}

.centerjustify h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -15px;
}

.column {
    padding: 0 15px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.left {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
}

.right {
    flex: 0 0 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.row--2 .left {
    flex: 0 0 70%;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.row--2 .right {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
}

.team {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .left,
    .right,
    .row--2 .right,
    .row--2 .left {
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .row--2 .right {
        order: 1;
    }
    .row--2 .left {
        order: 2;
    }
    .right,
    .left .row--2 .right,
    .row--2 .left {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately; padding' does not apply to `table-header-group` and `table-footer-group` so when you get to your mobile views, they are ignored.

You can read more about it here if you want: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding

I would advise to place the padding into your `row` class such as

```
.row {
  display: table;
  padding: 10px;
 }
```

And then you can style the way you want it.

If you want to keep `table-header-group` and `table-footer-group` in your media query, you cannot leave your padding in `.left`, `.left2`, `.right` or `.right2`.
Hope that it helps :)

Comment: But then there is no padding between the two columns when they're stacked on top of each other..

Comment: @Weronika That is true and something I did not address in my reply but you would need to use another wrapper or a tag to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

try just changing the position of the objects in that row by a media query. Don't forget the viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
 .row--2 .left {
float: left;
flex: 0 0 70%;
max-width: 70%;
   }

.row--2 .right {
 float: right;
flex: 0 0 30%;
max-width: 30%;
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .row--2 .left {
  float: right;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  }

 .row--2 .right {
  float: left;
  flex: 0 0 30%; 
  max-width: 30%;
   }
   }
   </style>
```